# Can Oracle PL/SQL CASE statement include a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
CASE
 WHEN number IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
```

Instead I want to have a query in the place of the list, like so:

```
CASE
 WHEN number IN (SELECT num_val FROM some_table) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
```

I can't seem to get this to work. Also, here is an example of the query.

```
    SELECT number, (CASE
     WHEN number IN (SELECT num_val FROM some_table) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS YES_NO 
    FROM some_other_table;
```

Comment: Yes they can. see documentation here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm

Comment: What bad things actually happen with that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  See an example below that would do what you are intending.  The difference is that it uses `EXISTS` instead of `IN`.

```
SELECT a.number, 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT null FROM some_table b where b.num_val = a.number)
             THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
        END) AS YES_NO 
    FROM some_other_table a;
```

**EDIT:**
I confess: I like the answers given by the others better personally.

However, there will be a difference between this query and the others depending on your data.

If for a value `number` in the table `some_other_table` you can have many matching entries of `num_val` in the table `some_table`, then the other answers will return duplicate rows.  This query will not.

That said, if you take the `left join` queries given by the others, and add a `group by`, then you won't get the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using an OUTER JOIN instead of trying to use a subquery in a CASE expression:

```
SELECT t.NUMBER, 
       CASE
         WHEN s.NUM_VAL IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
       END AS YES_NO
  FROM SOME_OTHER_TABLE t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SOME_TABLE s
    ON s.NUM_VAL = t.NUMBER
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to join the tables and do a decode.

```
with x as
(
    select 1 as num from dual
    union
    select 2 as num from dual
    union
    select 3 as num from dual
),
y as 
(
    select 1 as num from dual
    union
    select 2 as num from dual
    union
    select 4 as num from dual
)
select x.num, decode(y.num, null, 'N','Y') as yes_no
from x
left outer join y on (x.num = y.num)
```

Output:

```
NUM YES_NO
1   Y
2   Y
3   N
```

Comment: I was leaning towards doing a left outer join, thanks for the feed back :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery in case statement:

select
case dummy
when 'X' then (select 'TRUE' from dual)
else 'FALSE'
end TEST
from dual;

### TEST

TRUE

select
case (select 'XXX' from dual)
when 'XXX' then 'TRUE'
else 'FALSE'
end TEST
from dual;

### TEST

TRUE